# How can I fix the drop-down columns in the SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-administration

I encountered the following problem on multiple SharePoint lists: When you open a SharePoint list and click on the choice column, the drop-down list is appearing but you cannot be closed. Eventually, you have multiple drop-down lists appearing on the list, which causes a lot of confusion and discomfort while filling the form.

The issue is present on the old lists and as well as on relatively recent lists.

Do you have any ideas how to solve the existing "issue" or maybe find some workaround?

[image: Issue image]

Comment: Can you try clicking again on column cell OR outside of list view and see if it closes?

Comment: Did you insert any JavaScript code on the Master Page ?

Comment: Hi,

by clicking on the outside of the list (white space) the columns still remain open, the only workaround that I have found is as follows: you choose one option and then delete it by clicking on the cross button appearing next to the entered value. But i think this is too complex.. 

No, i have not entered a JavaScript code..

Comment: Seems others are also facing this issue, [reference](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/sharepoint-choice-field-issue-clicking-away/m-p/3659248/highlight/false#M65401). Raise support ticket with Microsoft: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide#online-support